# Discord script to send private messages to friends without them being in a channel

Tags: scripting, discord, message

I am running a business regarding selling/buying online things and I am mainly using Discord to contact my suppliers/clients. It grew quite tiresome to manually send private messages to each one of my suppliers, and to organize contacts with the current discord interface (outside of specific servers)

What I am interested in is: can I create a script that, when I run it, would send a private message to multiple people in my friends list (being given a list of discord names), WITHOUT using a discord server? The server/channel option is not viable for me, nor is using another app. I would start building that in any programming language, I am just interested if it's possible as I have found no information regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Discord Accounts can only message other accounts that they're either in a server with or are friends with. Discord Bots can't add friends, and if they were in a server with all of your clients that would defeat the purpose. A hypothetical solution would be to invite all of them to a Discord Server with no text channels and then have the bot message them from there, which is 100% possible and would be really easy to do.